# How to use Highland's wrapCallback with an n-arity function?

Tags: highland.js

I'd like to use a method (from jsonist) with the following structure:
`jsonist.get(uri, options, callback)`

`uri` and `options` are needed (options for passing a certain header)

However I'm not certain that Highland's wrapCallback can handle the two options here (minus the callback)

`const H = require('highland')
const req = H.wrapCallback(jsonist.get)
req(uri, options).apply(H.log)`

With this the stream is logged, not the data

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either specify the params *inside* `wrapCallback`:

```
const req = H.wrapCallback((uri, options, cb) => get(uri, options, cb))

req('some.uri', { options })
```

Or you could use a generator directly if the callback has artiy > 2:

```
const req = (uri, options) => H(push => {
  get(uri, options, (err, res, body) => {
    push(err, body)
    push(null, h.nil)
  })
})

req('some.uri', { options })
```